# [PHP][SQL Server Mail] Error: Profile name is not valid

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Intento mandar un correo a una cuenta usando SQL Server mediante código PHP. El código PHP es el siguiente:

```
$callmailproc= "EXEC sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name='Ocelot',
            @recipients='xxxxe@xxxx.com',
            @reply_to = 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
        @subject='Cliente[a] Asunto[a]',
        @body='Enlace a página click aquí',
        @body_format = 'HTML',
      @importance = 'Low',
        @sensitivity = 'Private'";

            $profilename = 'Ocelot';
            $recipients = 'mtonorte@inmotechnia.com';
            $subject='Prueba';
            $body = 'Esto es una prueba';
            $params = array(
                             array($profilename, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                             array($recipients, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                             array($subject, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                             array($body, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                             );

            $use_msdb = sqlsrv_query($conexion,'use msdb');
            $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conexion, $callmailproc, $params);
            if( $stmt3 === false )
            {
                 echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
                 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
        }
```

He creado una cuenta, un nombre de perfil y los he juntado mediante el siguiente código SQL:

```
use msdb
go

/*CREAR LA CUENTA*/

sysmail_add_account_sp   
     @account_name =  'Ocelot', /*Nombre de cuenta*/
     @description = 'Esta es la cuenta del asistente de mensajes de usuarios', /*Descripcion de la cuenta*/
     @email_address =  'mtonorte@inmotechnia.com' ,  /*Correo de Origen*/
     @display_name =  'Empleado Inmotechnia' ,  /*El nombre que sale encima del Asunto*/
     @replyto_address =  'noresponder@gmail.com' ,  /*La cuenta a la que el cliente manda las respuestas*/
     @mailserver_name =  'smtp.gmail.com', /*Dirección IP del servidor de correo SMTP*/
     @mailserver_type =  'SMTP' , /*Tipo de servidor de correo*/
     @port =  '587',  /*Numero de puerto para el servidor de correo electrónico*/
     @username =  'Ocelot', /*Nombre de usuario*/
     @password =  'Admin1234', /*Contraseña de Usuario*/
     @enable_ssl =  TRUE /*Cifra el correo para que sea más seguro (BIT)*/

/*CREAR EL NOMBRE DE PERFIL*/

sysmail_add_profile_sp @profile_name = 'Ocelot'

/*JUNTARLOS*/

sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp 
    /*@profile_id = '5'  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante la id de prfil*/*/
    @profile_name = 'Ocelot' ,  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante el nombre de perfil*/
    /*@account_id = '5'  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante la id de la cuenta*/*/
    @account_name = 'Ocelot',  /*se asocia el perfil a la cuenta mediante el nombre de cuenta*/ 
    @sequence_number = 1 /*Determina el número de cuentas que se utilizan en el perfil (INT)*/
```

También le he dado el rol de "Database Mail user role"

[image: dar rol]

Se que es mucho código, he intentado dejarlo lo más claro posible mediante comentarios.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema de permisos, he puesto el usuario con el rol de sysadmin y funciona, sé que no es la mejor idea, pero de momento es la única forma que tengo para que funcione, si alguien sabe que permiso en específico hay que poner, para no darle ese rol tan importante al usuario, se agradece